# Parse yml file into tree

Tags: java, parsing, tree, yaml

I have a yml file that looks like this:

```
STONE:
  - stone
  - stone block
  - smooth stone
WOOD:
  OAK_WOOD:
    - wood
    - oak wood
  SPRUCE_WOOD:
    - spruce wood
    - spruce wood block
```

There can be an infinite amount of children on any node.

I need to parse this into a Tree object in java. The root node would look something like this, when printed:

```
{STONE=[stone, stone block, smooth stone], WOOD=[OAK_WOOD=[wood, oak wood], SPRUCE_WOOD=[spruce wood, spruce wood block] ] }
```

How would I do this? I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: +1 for clear requirements. I have an idea of how to do this, when I write it I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

[Snakeyaml](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/) would do that pretty much out of the box. The tree structure you want is already the core of the YAML representation model, though that model itself is language independent. The output is just another presentation (called flow style by YAML) of the same model.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from one type of data to another, in this case YAML to JSON or YAML to POJO might be for several reasons.

- loading values into memory for operation on by POJO. Requires the Mapping of values into POJO classes, `ObjectMappers` are used in [Jeremy's question from Jan 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54160205/6345724)
- Transforming values for display or serialisation. From one static structure to another (YAML -> HTML, or YAML -> JSON). Can be referred to as `Templating` or `template engine`