# Parse a List of objects from YAML file

Tags: java, yaml

I am attempting to parse my Yaml file to a list of object But I am getting the following error.

```
Method threw 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException' exception.
```

My Java code:

```
public class ViewResultsModel
{
   @JsonProperty
   List<FileModel> files;

   public ViewResultsModel()
   {
   }

   public ViewResultsModel(List<FileModel> files)
   {
      this.files = files;
   }
 // getters and setters omitted
}


public class FileModel
{
   @JsonProperty
   String fileType;
   @JsonProperty
   String destination;
   @JsonProperty
   String filePath;
 // getters and setters omitted
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      File file = new File("Template.yaml");
      final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory()); // jackson databind
      mapper.readValue(file, ViewResultsModel.class);
   }
```

The YAML file:

```
file:
  fileType: TXT
  fileDestination: there
  filePath: C:/

file:
  fileType: PDF
  fileDestination: here
  filePath: C:/
```

I want to read the Yaml and create a List of FileModel objects

Comment: I can change the YAML structure if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your YAML objects have a member `fileDestination` which your Java class does not know. Instead of

```java
@JsonProperty
String destination;
```

try

```java
@JsonProperty("fileDestination")
String destination;
```

BTW, your input is not legal YAML. You *two* items name `file` where only one is possible. Did you want to build a list?

Answer (score 0):

You have the below line where you specify your `ViewResultsModel` class:

```
mapper.readValue(file, ViewResultsModel.class);
```

However your actual fields to be mapped are in your `FileModel` class